# Divergence criteria of Secant method on $\arctan(x)$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, secant

I want to make sure I understand when the secant method will not converge as compared to the Newton's method.

When I look at $\arctan(x)$ and try to determine the initial guesses for which it will converge, and those for which it won't, I've come up with the following:

For Newton's method, when $|x_0| < 2$, the method will converge.  and diverges otherwise.

For Secant method, when both $|x_0| < 2$, and $|x_1| < 2$ (since it requires 2 initial guesses) the the method converges, and diverges otherwise.

Can someone help me determine if this is correct?  thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct.

For $f(x)=\arctan x$, Newton's method is
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-(1+x_n^2)\arctan(x_n)
$$
so will give $\lvert x_{n+1}\rvert<\lvert x_n\rvert$ if $\lvert x_n\rvert<\xi$, where $\xi\approx 1.39$ is the unique positive solution of $\arctan(\xi)=2\xi/(1+\xi^2)$.  For starting value bigger in magnitude that $\xi$, the iterates diverges, changing sign with every iteration.

The secant method can converge for large starting values of $\lvert x_0\rvert, \lvert x_1\rvert$ when, e.g., $x_0=-x_1$ and also when they are close enough in magnitude such as $(x_0,x_1)=(-30,29.9)$ (so eventually some $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ are close to $(0,0)$).

Comment: Thanks.  How did you come up with the expression $\arctan(\xi)=2\xi/(1+\xi^2)$?  That's brilliant, I actually tried it out.  

And for the secant method, I was just playing with this and discoveredthat myself but I can't find exactly what distance consecutive starting values must be in order for this to converge.  HOw do I determine the upper bound on  $|x_0 - x_|1$ such that it still converges?

Comment: At first I thought it was concavity that you were computing, but when I compute the concavity of $arctan(x)$ I get $\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ whereas you have $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ (i.e. with no square in the denominator).  

Is that a typ0?

Comment: How did you get that expression?

Comment: Oops, I really do mean $/(1+\xi^2)$.  The "critical" case is if the iterates are $\xi,-\xi,\xi,-\xi,\dots$ (because we know the iterates are moving towards $0$ but can overshoot).  So feeding it into the defining equation $x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$ yields $2\xi=\arctan(\xi)(1+\xi^2)$, or equivalently $\arctan\xi=2\xi/(1+\xi^2)$.